# How to call a stored procedure / macros on teradata from informatica cloud?

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

I am trying to call a macro on Teradata from Informatica cloud but I was not able to achieve any success I tried SQL transformation, it works only for SQL server and oracle but not for teradata. Anyone has any idea how to call a macro on Teradata from the Informatica cloud.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to call a pre or post action the runs code on the O/S to trigger the macro. I generally use Python for pre and post actions as it is portable across O/Ss.

Answer (score 0):

in the post sql section of the target, you can call your stored procedure (exec spname)